# How to ask if I have saved my text document before closing the jframe

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, key-events

I'm developing a text editor and I need to check whether I have saved chances typed (even a space) in my Text Area.

If I have typed even a space, the dialog should pop and ask me to save the text before closing the application.

I need to define all the keys in a single way without checking all the keyboards keys are pressed or not... This is my code:

```
 private void isAnyKeyWasPressed() {
    jTextPane1.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyChar()==e.VK_0 || e.getKeyChar()==e.VK_1) {//need to define all the keyboard keys without defining one by one like this
                //my dialog box goes here
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ýou normally dont ask if he has saved, ask if he *wants* to save...

Comment: Could you give me any help regarding that??? @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ

Comment: DocumentEvent/Listener and/or(together with) DocumentFilter is/are designated for JTextComponent

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ : What if I have already saved the document and when I pressed the close button, it should be closing right??? If I have not saved it, it should be asking to save...

Comment: @mKorbel: can you define a code sample for that? or can you give me the procedure?

Comment: You could maintain a hash of the text between saves, if the hash has changed, then you need to save it

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that? @MadProgrammer

Comment: `String#hashcode` might be the simplest

Comment: Okay thank you very much @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are asking how to detect whether a document in a `JTextPane` was edited or not. Listening to keys is not optimal. I would rather recommend one of two ways:

A) Listen to changes to the underlying document:

```
    jTextPanel.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            isModified=true;                
        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            isModified=true;                
        }
        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            isModified=true;                
        }            
    });
```

The field `isModified` has to be initialized to `false`, and will be set to `true`whenever the document is changed in any way. You have to reset it to false after saving.

B) Keep a copy of the original document and compare both when the frame is about to be closed. How you do this depends a bit on the kind of document that you have. If it is an HTMLDocument, then comparing the actual HTML source code is the most accurate method:

Before editing starts:

```
HTMLDocument doc=(HTMLDocument)jTextPanel.getDocument();
String originalHtml=getHTML(doc);
```

After editing / upon closing the frame:

```
HTMLDocument doc=(HTMLDocument)jTextPanel.getDocument();
String editedHtml=getHTML(doc);
if(!editedHtml.equals(originalHtml))
   // ... text has been edited
```

The `getHTML()` method:

```
public String getHTML(HTMLDocument doc){
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    kit.write(writer, doc, 0, doc.getLength());
    return writer.toString();
}
```

The advantage of approach B) is that you don't have to check each edit operation (the overhead of which is negligible in most cases, though) and that you can accurately detect when changes have been reverted (e.g. user added text, then deleted that text, or an undo has been performed).

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. :)

Answer (score 1):

You do **not** want to listen for key events.

Instead, you want to track a "unsaved property" within the class that wraps around your different components. Any time the user makes **any** change to the editor (more specifically to the underlying **[model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html)** object); you set that property to `true`.

Every time the user saves, you turn the property to `false`.

And whenever the user tells the application to shutdown, you check that property, and if it is `true` - you ask the user if he wants to save.

Do **not** get into a mode where "one action" directly triggers another one.

Edit: just to make that clear - with property I mean that you add a **field** to your class, very much like the `isModified` that the other answer already suggests.

Comment: How can I check for unsaved property?

Comment: I have upvoted it because the code is working fine, but my ambition is for any kind of files (_not only HTML files_)...

Comment: Sorry, but it seems that you are absolutely **overburdening** yourself. He is using that HTMLModel as **example** (the answer reads "if it is an HTMLDocument"!) ... and we are talking really basic stuff here which you don't get. At the same point you want to create a complex Swing UI. That wont work. You have to **understand** the things you are doing.

Comment: And beyond that: SO is not about asking more questions in comments. If you do that, and hope for the other site to be helpful beyond the original answer ... then well, ask yourself: what might the other site motivate to help me beyond that point? For sure not an explanation why you upvoted elsewhere.